# What happens after we replace a Fragment in a Transaction

Tags: android

I want to know

```
getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(
                        R.id.main,
                        Fragment.instantiate(LoadingScreen.this,
                                "com.myapp.fragments.fragment1",
                                bundle)).commit();
```

and then later on we call

```
  getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(
                            R.id.main,
                            Fragment.instantiate(LoadingScreen.this,
                                    "com.myapp.fragments.fragment2",
                                    bundle)).commit();
```

What happens to the Fragment1 view ? Will it be destroyed automatically, do we have to manage any garbage collection on this ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the note on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace):

> When you remove or replace a fragment and add the transaction to the back stack, the fragment that is removed is stopped (not destroyed). If the user navigates back to restore the fragment, it restarts. If you do not add the transaction to the back stack, then the fragment is destroyed when removed or replaced.

Comment: If i have a lot of transactions in the above format, is it better to use a adapter like the FragmentStatePagerAdapter or the simpler way above ?

Comment: IMO, if you have a lot of fragments, I think the FragmentStatePagerAdapter  would be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please tell me about some difference that the adapter approach would improve ?